# Is there a better and compact way to represent the expansion of products of polynomials?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

Objective: to show the expansion process as readable as possible so we don't run the risk of misreading the coefficients of the corresponding terms of the expanded, long expressions.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% this line is not used in the production
\begin{align*}
(x^2 +x +1)(3x^2 -2x +1)(x^2 +5x -3)
&= \! 
   \begin{alignedat}[t]{4}
      (x^2 +x +1)(3x^4  &&{}+15x^3  &&{}-9x^2 \\
                        &&{}-2x^3   &&{}-10x^2 &&{}+6x \\
                        &&          &&{}+x^2   &&{}+5x &&{}-3 )
   \end{alignedat}\\
&= (x^2 +x +1)(3x^4 +13x^3 -18x^2 +11x -3)\\
&= \!
   \begin{alignedat}[t]{7}
     3x^6  &&{}+13x^5 &&{}-18x^4 &&{}+11x^3  &&{}-3x^2 \\
           &&{}+3x^5  &&{}+13x^4 &&{}-18x^3  &&{}+11x^2  &&{}-3x \\
           &&         &&{}+3x^4  &&{}+13x^3  &&{}-18x^2  &&{}+11x  &&{}-3
   \end{alignedat}\\
&= 3x^6 +16x^5 -2x^4 +6x^3 -10x^2 +8x -3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question: Is there a better approach to do so?

Comment: Has this something to do with TeX and friends? Probably http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ is better.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you're not trying to get a specific output, I feel this question is off-topic here.

Comment: @Jubobs: I want to get the same output or better but with more compact code.

Comment: These `alignedat` you use… For me, it's more clear if you don't use them, just “inline math”.

Comment: @FifaEarthCup2014: "...with more compact code." > [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @All: Thanks for retagging, commenting, linking, etc. :-)

Comment: It looks to me like the `\wall` command from the [`nath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nath) package is taylor-made for this sort of thing. (See section 20, pp. 11-12 of the documentation.)

Comment: I'd suggest aligning the binary operators are well to make it more readable. Otherwise it looks great.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I will follow your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Or use P(x) &= (x^2 etc for the first line.

Answer (score 2):

I used right alignment so that the exponents would line up.  Personally, I would have also aligned the plus and minus signs, but this is closer to the original.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\offset}% array row spacing
\setlength{\offset}{\arraystretch\ht\strutbox}
\addtolength{\offset}{\arraystretch\dp\strutbox}
\settowidth{\arraycolsep}{$\,$}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
P(x) &= (x^2 +x +1)(3x^2 -2x +1)(x^2 +5x -3) \\
&= (x^2 +x +1)
\raisebox{-\offset}{$\hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
\begin{array}{rrrrr}\displaystyle
  (3x^4 &+\,15x^3 &-\,9 x^2 \\
        &-\,2x^3  &-\,10x^2 &+\,6x \\
        &         &+\,x^2   &+\,5x &-\,3)
  \end{array}$} \\
&= (x^2 +x +1)(3x^4 +13x^3 -18x^2 +11x -3)\\
&= \raisebox{-\offset}{$\hspace{-\arraycolsep}%
\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}\displaystyle
  3x^6  &+\,13x^5 &-\,18x^4 &+\,11x^3  &-\,3x^2 \\
        &+\,3x^5  &+\,13x^4 &-\,18x^3  &+\,11x^2  &-\,3x \\
        &         &+\,3x^4  &+\,13x^3  &-\,18x^2  &+\,11x  &-\,3
  \end{array}$} \\
&= 3x^6 +16x^5 -2x^4 +6x^3 -10x^2 +8x -3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: equation]

Comment: It becomes less and  less compact. :-)